# Starring and messy edges when smoothing or using sub surf modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have a problem that when I apply a SubSurf modifier to my project, it has some starring and messy edges around the connection of my spheres. My goal is to have a string of "bubbles" which are smooth. I would also like to be able to rig them under one armature. The seams for UV unwrapping should be able to be placed where the spheres connect. I have used a Boolean modifier to merge the spheres. The problem I am having is that when I try to smooth out the spheres, starring occurs at the top and bottom of them. I have tried using loop cuts, the smooth option in the tools menu, and starting with a high-poly model, but none of that worked for me.

Here is an example of the starring:

[image]

Here is how the spheres should connect (Please ignore the starring and high-poly count):

[image]
[image]

And here is a download to what I would like to end up smoothing out: http://www.mediafire.com/file/e6xeb5i74ii2t79/BugZHugSave3.blend1

If you have questions, please ask.

Comment: HI. Next time please upload images using the built-in image uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid Boolean as much as possible. Often it doesn't give a good topology.

If you want to keep your object:

- Go in Edit mode, select all and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to make Normals Consistent.
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* to delete all the vertices that are very close to each others. Play with the parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel (<kbd>T</kbd> to display).
- In *Object* mode, increase the *View Subdivisions* of your Subsurf modifier and press Smooth in the *T* panel > *Tools* > *Shading*. You could get something not too ugly.

But you should redo your object this way:

- Create a sphere, rotate it, cut its top.
- Duplicate this sphere and rotate it 180°.
- Merge the two spheres with the *Snap* tool enabled (horizontal bottom menu of the 3D view), *Type of element* > *Vertex*, and press the *Automatically merge vertices* option.
- Scale down one of the sphere, add an edge loop to correct the topology.

[image]

Comment: I have messed around this for a while, and have run into a problem. My goal is to have the sphere rounded, but the connection remains un-curved, and I cannot do that with your solution. Sorry if I did not make it clear enough in my question.

Comment: again, don't use Boolean, start again from scratch with the method I've shown you, you need to have a good topology

Comment: How can I get rid of the curvature where the two spheres connect and keep it consistent throughout the whole model?

Comment: have you tried the second method?

Comment: Yes. Whenever I try and apple Sub-Surf, I get a bit of curvature, like you did. I have tried moving the spheres closer together, but There is still some curvature at the joint.

Comment: in that case just add an edge loop close to the one you want to be sharp

Comment: I am silly for not seeing the answer. Thank you for your help!